# Can cocoapods commands be run without touching the code dependencies?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcconfig, xcodeproj

I work on a team that is an iOS contractor for a larger company.  We are helping the large company build a iOS app with Xcode and we use Cocoapods to manage our dependencies in the project.  However, the large company has internal Cocoapods that are hosted behind their firewall that we, the contractors, cannot see or touch.  This produces many issues for the developers outside the firewall not the least of which is that '`pod update`' and '`pod install`' both fail with:

```
Update all pods
Cloning spec repo `xxx-podName` from `https://xxxx.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://xxxxx.git` named `xxx-podName`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

Because these repos/pods rarely are changed outside of our project we don't usually need to actually pull down new/updated code from them.  Still there are many important side-effects from the 'pod' commands that our team would like to be able to accomplish, such as the re-structuring/regeneration of the workspace and project files along with other the auto-magic processes that occur when 'update' or 'install' are run (such as the building of shell scripts).

Is there a 'contactless' way to rebuild or create the correct project/target/workspace structuring for an Xcode project with cocoapods that can succeed even if the machine running the command cannot access the hosted pods?

Comment: Yes, download the source once and add them as local pods.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot access the pod's repository.  Also, even if we could, because the pod source path is saved in our project source repository that would either affect all project users or require the maintenance of a separate SC branch.